# Android + update getLocationInWindow at any time?

Tags: android, view

I'm interested in knowing an animated view's current location at any given time.  What's the best way to handle this?

```
int[] loc = new int[2]; 
MyListView.this.findViewById(R.id.tvTop).getLocationInWindow(loc);
final int tvTopX = loc[0];
Log.e("---xLocation---", Integer.toString(tvTopX));
```

This seems to trace the same value, even after an animation.  Do I need to invalidate or something to get the location value to update? Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638342/incorrect-coordinates-from-getlocationonscreen-getlocationinwindow) maybe covers your needs, too.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  That's actually where I got the code above.  :)  I'll post back if I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Android <3.0 animation not currently change view position. You can animate view by changing layout params to track current position or use http://nineoldandroids.com/ for access Android 3.0 Animation API on older Android versions. 
Here is a link with description http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html