# Confusion between getLocationInWindow and getLocationOnScreen

Tags: android

What I have understood is that `getLocationOnScreen` returns location with added height of status bar (or actionbar or title bar too ?) in Y axis from very top-left of screen corner.

And `getLocationInWindow` returns location from top-left of root content view of activity.

Now, everything seems to make sense. But when Im trying to get location using `getLocationOnScreen` and `getLocationInWindow`, they both return same location of a button with added height of status bar. For `getLocationOnScreen` it seems correct but for `getLocationInWindow` it seems wrong.

Is there something I'm missing ? or its just buggy ? I tested this in API-4 and API-14.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getLocationOnScreen() vs getLocationInWindow()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672891/getlocationonscreen-vs-getlocationinwindow)

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question has been answered before, I think it is still worth an effort to make this clearer.

If you look into the code of getLocationOnScreen and getLocationInWindow:

```
public void getLocationOnScreen(int[] outLocation) {
    // It calls the getLocationInWindow
    getLocationInWindow(outLocation);

    // and adjust accordingly in case the window is not the top-level window 
    final AttachInfo info = mAttachInfo;
    if (info != null) {
        outLocation[0] += info.mWindowLeft; // refer image below
        outLocation[1] += info.mWindowTop; // refer image below
    }
}

public void getLocationInWindow(int[] outLocation) {
    // do my calculation here 
    // by traversing views contained in this window (in a single tree of views) 
    ...
}
```

This is further explained in the image below, where blue indicates screen & red indicates window:

[image]

It is important to note that window can be your top-level window (covers the entire screen), or other custom windows such as dialog.

So, going back to your questions:

> getLocationOnScreen returns location with added height of status bar

That's right. Your phone's screen includes the status bar's view

> getLocationOnScreen and getLocationInWindow, they both return same location of a button with added height of status bar

That is because the window you are working with is the top level window that covers your entire phone's screen.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked here: [getLocationOnScreen() vs getLocationInWindow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672891/getlocationonscreen-vs-getlocationinwindow) although the accepted answer is not correct, as stated by @groucho.

I could copy his answer but I think it is better if you check it there!

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, I did quite deep search before posting here. I had to use root view of activity then did some calculation. :)