# Popup windows in StickyGridHeader display wrong position

Tags: android, android-gridview

I use [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) library to create an Gridview like [snapfish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapfish.mobile). Here is my expected layout:

[image]

I show a popup windows when touching a button on header view (red arrow) instead of check box. The problem is my popup window always display wrong position. From debugging window, I can see it has the **same location with sticky header**, but I turned off sticky header for my gridview by using `StickyGridHeadersGridView.setAreHeadersSticky(false);`

Here is my adapter header:

```
    public View getHeaderView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final HeaderViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header_gallery, null);
                viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tvImagePrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvImagePrice);
                viewHolder.btnTouch = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnTouch);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();       
            }

            ImageGroup item = headers.get(position);    
            viewHolder.tvImagePrice.setText(item.getPriceString());

            viewHolder.btnTouch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int[] location      = new int[2];

                    viewHolder.btnTouch.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                    // location always is [905,59] for every header item
                    System.out.println("location = " + location[0] + "," + location[1]);

                    // show popup on this location:
                    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0], location[1]);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

If I show a popup in child view instead of header, the popup window show correctly. 
Is there something wrong?

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet... try getting the location from the `View` that was clicked: `v.getLocationOnScreen(location);` instead of the instance from `viewHolder`.

Comment: I tried but it still shows on the top of gridview. Because this library tried to stick the header view on top by attach and detach view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like there is no way to get header item position correctly, because this library used attach and detach header view in [StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders/StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper.java#L179)

```
HeaderFillerView v = getHeaderFillerView(adapterPosition.mHeader, convertView, parent);
View view = mDelegate.getHeaderView(adapterPosition.mHeader, (View)v.getTag(), parent);
mGridView.detachHeader((View) v.getTag());
v.setTag(view);
mGridView.attachHeader(view);
convertView = v;
mLastHeaderViewSeen = v;
v.forceLayout();
```

Actually, it called `dispatchAttachedToWindow` and `dispatchDetachedFromWindow` of view class by reflection. And it caused getting wrong windows on entire screen as `nosacky` said. 
Now I am quit and replace this StickyGridHeaders by Listview with Header item and Gridview item. This isn't a best way but it can work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting the windows location inside the other window and not the location on the entire screen. Take a look at this question for more details: [getLocationOnScreen() vs getLocationInWindow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672891/getlocationonscreen-vs-getlocationinwindow)

Comment: I know what you mean but how can I solve this issue?