# How to get the position of the child of the child of a linear layout?

Tags: java, android

This is my xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:rotation="180">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/cols">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/col1">
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/col2">
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
            <Button .../>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want click listener on the all buttons and I want to have the position when I click on a button. I tried several things without success.Indeed, I can't  to have the clicked button position.

Comment: Which position do you need? The one of the clicked `Button` or the one of the point of the touch screen where you clicked (disregarding the specific view element).

Comment: The one of the clicked Button

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672891/getlocationonscreen-vs-getlocationinwindow) about `getLocationOnScreen()` and `getLocationInWindow()`, which are methods of the class `View` in Android

Comment: I don't understand this example. I don't see the relationship with what I want to do ...

Comment: It gives you the coordinates of the view element (in your case `Button`) relative to the display or parent view. If this is not what you wanted, please describe your idea of *position* used in your question.

Comment: No, it is not that. I want to put a "setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () ..." on each button and when I press a button I want it to return an int indicating that position (for exemple first button press will return to me an int equal to 0)

Comment: Oh, its position **inside a datastructure**, the index?

Comment: More simple it can also work with my code. When I click on a column I must have the position of the column (linearlayout).

Comment: OK, in that case I would store the `Button`s in a `List<Button>` or an array (`Button[]`) in the desired order (bottom left first, middle bottom second and so on) and use that in the listener...

Comment: Ok then, see the answer by @SusmitAgrawal

Comment: I will already do that it's not work. So I change my code. It's possible to have the position of the linearlayout col1, col2, ... When I click on ?

Comment: Please show some Java code you have tried so far.

Comment: @deHaar and this method not work because I have this when I click: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7

Comment: Maybe due to using `i` instead of `j` in `play(player, i)`? Why are you iterating with `j` when using `i` as index? If the length of an array or list is 7 then its last index is 6 --> `i = 7` --> `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I try with j. Now, the apps not crash but j always is 6. It's not good.

Comment: It makes the loop until the end so j = 6.

Comment: I find it. I will change the button to image and it's works ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic:

In your activity, do this:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.col1);
```

then, in every buttons's `onClick`:

```
for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(layout.getChildAt(i).equals(thisButton))//Replace thisButton with the variable name
    {
        //do something
        // i  represents the button's position in its immediate parent.
        break;
    }
}
```

The same logic can also apply for the LinearLayout `col2`

Comment: Oh, I have to put as much name as button? So I make the code multiply, I think it's not good at all.

Comment: You can use the same `for loop`, without the `if`,  to initialise the buttons as well, provided you use an array of buttons. The statement would be something like: `buttons[i] = layout.getChildAt(i);`