# How to add images in a linear layout and empty spaces where there is no images programatically in C#?Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZzHL.png)I have a set of images to be added.
I have to place one image in first row and the images in second row should start at the end of first row image

How can I achieve it with linearlayout in xamrin android?

Comment: Your question is quite vague can you be specific about what you want a visual representation would help

Comment: You want a kind of ”ladder” layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve it like following screenshot.
[image]

If so, you could used `linearLayout.SetPaddingRelative(imageView1.Drawable.IntrinsicWidth, 0,0,0);` to set the start of padding in following linearlayout.

there is my code.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout ll_layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.ll_layout);

        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);


        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);
        imageView1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Capture1);
        linearLayout1.AddView(imageView1);
        ll_layout.AddView(linearLayout1);

        LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout2.SetPaddingRelative(imageView1.Drawable.IntrinsicWidth, 0,0,0);
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(this);
        imageView2.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Capture2);
        linearLayout2.AddView(imageView2);
        ll_layout.AddView(linearLayout2);



    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10627299/leon-lu-msft Hey Thanks. I get to know about SetPaddingRelative.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10627299/leon-lu-msft But my problem is not exactly this. I have updated my question with attaching a sample image of what I need. How can I calculate the X & Y and fill them with empty views

Comment: You could use `getLocationOnScreen()` to get the X ,Y location of this control in the screen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672891/getlocationonscreen-vs-getlocationinwindow .Based on your screenshot, the value of Y is your control's height.