# Keep tracking of the position of a TableLayout?

Tags: android

How do I keep track of the position of a UI element, say a `TableLayout`?

What I mean by this is, whenever its position changes, there is some kind of event handler gets called and then inside the event handler code I can get the coordinate of this TableLayout (maybe the coordinates of its upper left corner)

A sample code will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any widget or layout has [onLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method which receives as parameters left, top, right and bottom positions. Base `android.view.View` class even has a listener for this event [onLayoutChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html), but `TableLayout` does not. So you can extend it and override `onLayout` method to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems that the overridden `onLayout` method does not get called when `TableLayout`'s absolute position changes.

Comment: What if you override `onLayout` of `TableLayout`'s parent?

Comment: Thanks for this update. I tried it, but i didn't work. Then I realize that the parent of the `TableLayout` is `ScrollView`, so that I look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638342/incorrect-coordinates-from-getlocationonscreen-getlocationinwindow) to constantly get the absolute position of the `TableLayout` when user scrolls `ScrollView`.