# How to use a custom animation for hiding and showing ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I am making a custom animation which requires that the page content slides synchronously with my ActionBar. For that, I need to know the animation duration of hide() and show() actions.

```
Runnable animationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        animate(topSlideImage).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).translationYBy(-sectionHeight);
    }
};
```

My animation duration is **600ms**

Apart from knowing, I would want to change (duration, interpolator etc) ActionBar hide and show animations, any ideas on how to do the same.

**Edit #1**

I dig into the ActionBarImpl code and found that hide()/show() duration is [250 ms](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl.doHide%28boolean%29), and it internally uses cubic interpolator.

**Any ideas on how to use a custom animation for hiding and showing ActionBar ?**

Comment: .hide() uses this internally: [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#ActionBarImpl.doHide%28boolean%29)

Comment: Check this old stackoverflow question [how-to-hide-the-animation-of-actionbar-show-and-hide-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824472/how-to-hide-the-animation-of-actionbar-show-and-hide-in-android

Comment: Thanks 3mpty, I also found this link just now. Duration is 250 ms, along with cubic interpolator.