# Finding accurate coordinates of an image inside of an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates

I am trying to find the coordinates of an image inside of an ImageView, but I can't find a way to get accurate results. Here is the best solution I've found so far.

```
    int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];
    plate.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
    int x = img_coordinates[0];
    int y = img_coordinates[1];
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.plate_only, o);
    int w = bmp.getWidth();
    int h = bmp.getHeight();
```

The x value is correct for this, but the y is returning a value in the middle of the upper half of the image. Any suggestions on how to get an accurate y value, and/or a cleaner way of getting these coordinates? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In getLocationOnScreen() Y value includes status and notification bar height.
to exclude this you can take help from this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638342/incorrect-coordinates-from-getlocationonscreen-getlocationinwindow)..