# How to get exact position in pixels of my TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, position, android-view

I have a smartphone of 2560 x 1440 px. Now I am using this function for my `TextView`:

```
int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
txtAp.GetLocationInWindow(locationOnScreen);
```

It is supposed to give me the total x and y coordinates in pixels.
My `TextView` is pretty much in the middle of the screen, so supposedly at
(1280,770). But the function returns [69, 1111].

How can that be? If that is not the way of doing that, then what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a smartphone of 2560 x 1440 px... My `TextView` is pretty much in the middle of the screen, so supposedly at (1280,770).

Not correct, unless you talk about the center of the `TextView`. Any view is rendered on screen within its rectangle, so its coordinates are considered to be of [left, top, right, bottom].

The `GetLocationInWindow()` method returns (left, top) coordinates of a view. So (x = 69, y = 1111) looks to be meaningful for the left top corner of your `TextView` located in the middle of screen.

**Important note**: `GetLocationInWindow()` returns the coordinates w.r.t the root view, not actual window. You should [take the status bar height into consideration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2638342/3290339). And here is how you can calculate [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3407256/3290339).