# Android: how to get the Y position of a view in a scrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have two text views in a scrollView and I want to get their Y position when I tap them.

But I have tried many things in the debug console, always returning 0:

> subView.getY()
>
> subView.getScrollY()

What to do instead?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use getLocationOnScreen() method of view and pass int array and get 0 and 1 position for X and Y.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `getLocationOnScreen()` method of view and pass int array and get 0 and 1 position for X and Y.

Comment: For those who need to know how to use this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761184/14784590

Answer (score 0):

Use `textView.getTop()` and `textView.getBottom()`